# My react native app run only when remote debugger enable so on when i install app on device it will not work properly

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, remote-debugging

I created an app with facebook login in my app when I run it on emulator without remote debugger run then it does not work after facebook sends response I mean the state doesn't change. but when the debugger unable then it works fine. so when I created it apk then it not work after I click on facebook login.

please help me what I have to do for that
I am using firebase for authentication.

Comment: can you share some code? its hard to debug with the statement provided

Comment: Ok i will post some code like my app.js

Comment: Same issue. Dis you solve it?